# Changing Supported Orientations

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, windows-phone-7

I'm writing a Windows Phone app in C#. I have a setting `OrientationLock` that is supposed to lock the screen in portrait orientation. Unfortunately, I can't for the life of me get it to work. The setting saves and everything, I just can't figure out how to change the supported orientations in C#. Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (AppSettings.Default.OrientationLock)
    {
        this.SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.Portrait;
    }
    else
    {
        this.SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.PortraitOrLandscape;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Works just fine here in emulator and on Mango device.

Comment: Not sure, it just doesn't lock the orientation if the setting is set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually you have to move the code to the overridden `OnNavigatedTo` method (in page class) to update the supported orientations if coming back from the settings page... The constructor is only called once (if page was not tombstoned).

Comment: Ahhh. Okay. So when the setting gets changed it has to change that too. Thanks, I'll look in to that.

Comment: Yes. This way the setting is only checked once (on application start) if you navigate to the settings page, change it and navigate back to the page, it will not be updated... If you move it to OnNavigatedTo, it will update the setting every time you navigate to the page not only once (when constructor is called...)